# HQL fetch parent by children attribute and fetch this child also

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have following problem,

Imagine we have two entites

**Entity A**

**Entity B**

Entity A has linked list of B entities like this

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = [CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "a_to_b",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "a_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "b_id")]
    )
    val children = mutableListOf<B>()
```

Relation of these entities is M:N with simple connection table (holding just two ids)

I am basically trying to **retrieve all entities A that are related to entities B by given list of `B.id`s and fetch all B entities with this query**. So if I call `entityA.entityB[0].someProperty` I will not perform another query.

I've managed to get code to working state with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a 
FROM AtoB atob 
JOIN FETCH A a ON atob.a_id = a.id 
JOIN FETCH a.children 
WHERE atob.b_id IN :givenBids
```

But comparing to previous query (where I just used Spring data JPA to generate method from

```
findAllBychildrenId
```

Is my query above really slow. I know there is some overhead to fetch all children etc, but it is significantly slower (on some performance test run we are talking about maximal execution time of 2 seconds vs 15 seconds on custom query)

**Am I doing something wrong in sight or performance? It should be pretty same query as the generated one, just with selecting more columns (to "fetch" B data with one query)**